# AngularJS Digest issue

Tags: angularjs

I am having some troubles with angular digest.
I understand that angular defines and limit number of interations by default, but i want to have several iterations in simultaneos if some element changes.

**..updated plunkr (the plunkr crash, if you open the console you can see the digest error)**
http://plnkr.co/edit/lxiFdGkT5UZf2e4w20gw?p=info

this is an example of the app, as you can see i have several functions that detect if some input has changed (simple angularjs), but when i update the app and put a http get function to get the current iva instead of

```
var true_iva = 0;
if(item.iva == 1) {
   true_iva = 0.23;
} else if(item.iva == 2){
   true_iva = 0.13;
} else if(item.iva == 3){
   true_iva = 0.06;
} else if(item.iva == 4){
   true_iva = 0;
}
```

it give me the following error:

```
10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
```

Can you help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the `$http` call in your plunkr?

Comment: Right, we'd need to see that because right now it's not clear how/when you would resolve the promise for the call.

Comment: the thing is, i have vagrant running so my calls are local, so as the database. I will provide some kind of example.

Comment: I have given some sort of example, but the real one has a server function that for a given IvaId goes to the databse and returns the current iva value. the json is just to show the http get kind of example. I hope that it helps :/